# SQLite record not correct on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have an SQLite db with 19 records in it.  Of those records 18 have a "threatLevel" value of 1, and one of them has a "threatLevel" of 2.  The field is set to default to 1.  I recently changed the 19th record to "threatLevel" 2 for testing purposes.
I used [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) (a Firefox extension) to add the value directly to the sqlite file in my project.  I can query the table and it shows that the 19th record has a "threatLevel" of 2.
When I run my app in the simulator, the 19th record has a "threatLevel" of 1.  I have tried cleaning my build, uninstalling the app from the simulator, even removing the sqlite database from my project and readding it.  Nothing works.  SQLite Manager says it has a value of 2, but when the program is run it gets a value of 1.
The code to load it into the class from the DB is this:

```
primaryKey = pk;
    database = db;
    
    // Compile the query for retrieving City data.
    if (init_statement == nil){
        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=?";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    
    sqlite3_bind_int(init_statement, 1, primaryKey);
    if (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                LOAD THE FIRST 12 FIELDS HERE
        self.threat_level = sqlite3_column_int(init_statement, 13);
    } else {
        self.name = @"Nothing";
    }
```

**EDIT**
I just tried deleting the sqlite database from the project, and I moved it to my desktop to back it up.  I can still build and run my app.
So it's looking at an older version of my database, but Spotlight says there are no other versions on my machine except for the one on my desktop.
Any help here?

Comment: Why use Core Data? (Core Data is not in all versions of the Framework)

Comment: @Pselus Are you really targeting 2.x devices?

Comment: Of all the tech savvy people I know with an iphone have 3.0, but a lot of the non tech savvy people I know with iphones never bothered to move up to it. (including my wife and her friends)
That said, what is the benefit to using Core Data if it just wraps around SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to identify the name/path of the database that you are using as you're needing to provide the argument as part of sqlite3_open()?

```
if (sqlite3_open([dataFilePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

The database file is likely in the simulator. There is an option within the simulator to "Reset Content and Settings."

Comment: Reset Content and Settings fixed the issue for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` to list the files open by a process, which can hopefully help you nail down which database is being used. Find the process ID of your application with Activity Monitor or the like, and run `lsof -p <PID>` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using SELECT * you may want to use explicit column names in the select string...

Comment: in general it is better to use column names than '*' because if the column order in the table changes it will break the code.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your sqlite in your project - eg. Is it in your app bundle or are you writing it to the Documents folder for your app?

If you are writing it to the Documents folder for your app and running the simulator your file will be located in the Application Support folder for the iPhone Simulator

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/<application id>
```

Also I'll add a +1 to using Core Data in general - I just attended an Apple iPhone event and there are some significant efficiency and performance benefits to be gained by using Core Data over most of the other sqlite frameworks and especially over directly accessing the sqlite c api.